# How do I stop Xcode from letting me edit old projects in new projects

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I am new to Xcode and have been trying to make various projects to get acquainted with it. So I have this one project called calc and it is a calculator. Now I'm  trying to make another calculator app that is different but when I'm making the code in `viewcontroller.h` I will type similar lines of code and when I do it indicates with a little grey dot with a circle around it that I'm connected to my older project. When i click it it gives me links to other objects that are in different projects.

The dot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

That dot indicates that your `IBOutlet` is connected up to a `xib` file.

When you created your new project. Did you drag some old files into your new project? Then when you did that did you leave the

```
Copy items into destination group's folder (if needed)
```

check box unchecked? Because then you would have files that are from other projects. If you wanted a copy of the files you should check the previously mentioned check box when copying files across.

Comment: thanks helpful answer. however i did not drag new files and i don't know where that copy items checkbox is. could you tell me where. I'm on the current Xcode.

Comment: This checkbox appears on the dialog that appears when you drag files into your project or on the dialog that appears when you click `File -> Add Files To <your_project_name>...`

Comment: i just found it but it has never prompted me to go there when making a new project. is there a way to include this step when making a new project?

Comment: This is only an issue when adding files to a project. You say that it links you to files in a different project? Can you right click the file i the project navigator and click `Show in Finder` and confirm whether it is in the right projects directory?

Comment: yeah it says Im still in the new project but when i click the dot it gives menu as if i right clicked it and it shows me my objects from a different project

Comment: How are you confirming they are from a different project?

Comment: it says the name of the project folder in the main bar of the finder window and i have them saved to two different files which I've checked in. They do indeed contain separate files but its like the talk to each other